# Is there a more concise way to remove an entry from an array with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Below are several stabs at removing 3 from the array `[8,2,3,4]` using lodash.  The elegant syntax for removing an object from an array of objects makes me wonder if I just haven't figured out the right approach here.

```
> _.remove([8,2,3,4], 3)
  []
> x = [8,2,3,4]
  [8, 2, 3, 4]
> _.remove(x, 3)
  []
> x
  [8, 2, 3, 4]
> _.remove(x, {3: true})
  []
> x
  [8, 2, 3, 4]
> _.remove(x, [3])
  []
> x
  [8, 2, 3, 4]
> _.remove(x, function(val) { return val === 3; });
  [3]
> x
  [8, 2, 4]
```

Is there another way to remove a matching element from an array that would be similar to `_.remove(arrayOfObjs, {id:3})`

Comment: Have you read [the documentation for `_.remove()`?](https://lodash.com/docs#remove)

Comment: Yes @Pointy I have.  If I had found the answer there, I wouldn't have asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but not using `remove`. You can instead use [`pull`](https://lodash.com/docs#pull) to remove values from an array:

> Removes all provided values from array using `SameValueZero` for equality comparisons.

```
// pull modifies its argument:

x = [8, 2, 3, 4]
_.pull(x, 3)
x // => [8, 2, 4]

// pull also returns the modified array:

y = _.pull([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2, 3) //  => [1, 4, 5]
```